# android Parse.com get specific data

Tags: android, parse-platform

here is my screenshot

[image: http://i.imgur.com/JbllLKO.png]

in my activity.java

```
    btnSearchemail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearchemail);
    txtSearchemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSearchemail);

    Searchemail = txtSearchemail.getText().toString();

    txtFname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtFname);
    txtLname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLname);



    btnSearchemail.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery
                    .getQuery("account");
            query.whereEqualTo("email", Searchemail);
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                public void done(List<ParseObject> results, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        // results contains a list of all the emails found

                        for (ParseObject x : results) {
                            String fname = x.getString("firstName");
                            String lname = x.getString("lastName");


                        }
                        // i replace it here this is edited/updated
                        txtFname.setText(fname);
                        txtLname.setText(lname);

                    } else {
                        // error
                        Toast.makeText(Sample.this.getApplicationContext(),
                                "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

I want to retrieve specific data according to email that I put in my edittext. nothing happens again when i click the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to call a query. Note this function is asynchronous. Documentation can be found [here](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries).

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("account");
query.whereEqualTo("email", emailsave);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> results, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            // results contains a list of all the emails found
            for (ParseObject x : results) {                     
                 String fname = x.getString("firstName");
                 String lname = x.getString("lastName");
                 // Put breakpoint here and see what the variables contain
                 txtFname.setText(fname);
                 txtLname.setText(lanme)
            }
        } else {
            // error
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i want to display the firstname and lastname of given row, how can i do that?

Comment: if (e == null) {

String fname=query.get("firstName");
String lname= query.get("lastName");                                                               
             txtFname.setText(fname);
             txtFname.setText(lanme);

Comment: ^it is just an example

Comment: Updated the answer. Reading through the documentation will help you a lot.

Comment: I can't tell you why it's not working without having your project. The code I gave you should work. If you put break points in there then you can see what part is messing up and be more clear in your question.

Comment: @delhi hey man i use the breakpoints as you said.  my Searchemail/edittext contains "a"........String fname= value("a)", String lname=value("b") which is right data. but its not appearing on my activity.